# GCP-SQL setting multiple sql_mode flags at MySQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have recently migrated production database to GCP-SQL (MySQL) and for my web-application to work correctly, it needs TRADITIONAL+ALLOW_INVALID_DATES sql_mode. I see limitation of adding only one flag from GCP-console and at cli-mode it says need to have super privileges even if logged in as root user.

Support it not responding, maybe it's been converted to any paid plan, or similar, any known to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[There's a Feature Request open for this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36401681#comment2), but it hasn't been updated since 2017.

The workaround is to set the mode at the start of each new SQL connection using `SET SESSION sql_mode='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES'`.